# mysql last result based on date

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table

```
Sno TC   Date(dd/mm/yyyy)     Result  
1   tc_1 22/10/2010 11:28:27  Fail  
2   tc_1 21/11/2010 12:28:27  Pass  
3   tc_3 11/11/2010 09:20:22  Pass  
4   tc_3 12/11/2010 09:20:22  Pass
```

I want to get the most recent pass and most recent fail for each testcase.

Apart from returning the recent dates , is it possible to display the time in say like
'1 week ago' or
'2 weeks ago'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the most recent pass and fail

```
SELECT
  TC,
  Result,
  Max(TestDate)
FROM Table
GROUP BY TC, Result
```

To get a number of days to return

```
SELECT
  TC,
  Result,
  DateDiff(Max(TestDate), Now())
FROM Table
GROUP BY TC, Result
```

Comment: would it be possible to convert the `  DateDiff(Max(TestDate), Now())
` to display somethig like in WEEKS / months?

Comment: @Jpro ... yes its possible.  I would elaborate more but,  I believe I have given you enough to get started ... here is a helpful link  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html